# Android View.getContext() on null object error when pressing back button

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-view

In my main activity I have a spinner, when the user makes a selection on the spinner it makes an intent and starts activity2 but if the user tries to go back to the main activity the app crashes.

Main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Spinner spinner;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addItemsSpinner();
}

public void addItemsSpinner(){
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            for(int i = 1; i<=6; i++) {
                if (position == i ) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext().getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    intent.putExtra("sel", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Activity2:

```
public class Activity2 extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity2);
    Intent getSel = getIntent();
        String selection = getSel.getExtras().getString("sel");
        final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user);
        textViewToChange.setText(
                "user " + selection);

    setDateAndTime();
}

public void setDateAndTime(){
    String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
    textViewToChange.setText(
            "time " + currentDateTimeString);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

LogCat:

```
08-24 14:43:17.713    3063-3063/dbxprts.moldtech E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: dbxprts.moldtech, PID: 3063
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.view.View.getContext()' on a null object reference
        at dbxprts.moldtech.MainActivity$1.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:30)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:897)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.selectionChanged(AdapterView.java:884)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.checkSelectionChanged(AdapterView.java:1047)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.handleDataChanged(AdapterView.java:1027)
        at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:184)
        at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:507)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:697)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: convert `view.getContext().getApplicationContext()` and `view.getContext()` to `MainActivity.this` and see what happens

Comment: @pelotasplus thanks this solved the view get context error but now on when trying to recover the string from the intent in activity2 it gives me a "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference" :/

Comment: that is because you are starting activity in your code before passing extras to your intent, check the code i posted as answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext().getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    intent.putExtra("sel", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("sel", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: in addition, the exception you are getting is due to the reason that when back button is pressed, onResume() of MainActivity is called and at that time it is not able to identify the context and hence returning null

Comment: So onResume(); I have to create the intent again with its extra string?

Comment: Ohhh right so I was starting the activity and then passing the extra, thank you very much Aakash, its working now :)